# Image URL uploading after everything has loaded in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

```
function App() {

  const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);

  const [newMovieTitle, setNewMovieTitle] = useState("");
  const [newReleaseDate, setNewReleaseDate] = useState(0);
  const [isNewMovieOscar, setIsNewMovieOscar] = useState(false);
  
  const [newMovieUrl, setNewMovieUrl] = useState("");

  //update title state
  const [updatedTitle, setUpdatedTitle] = useState("");
  //file upload state
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(null);
  const moviesCollectionRef = collection(db, "movies");

  const getMovieList = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getDocs(moviesCollectionRef);
      const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
      setMovieList(filteredData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const onSubmitMovie = async () => {
    // await uploadFile();
    try {
      await uploadFile();
      await addDoc(moviesCollectionRef, {
        title: newMovieTitle,
        releaseDate: newReleaseDate,
        receivedAnOscar: isNewMovieOscar,
        userId: auth?.currentUser?.uid,
        movieUrl: newMovieUrl,
      });
      getMovieList();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  const uploadFile = async () => {
    const filesFolderRef = ref(storage, `projectFiles/${imageUpload.name + uniqid()}`);
   await uploadBytesResumable(filesFolderRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        console.log(url)
        setNewMovieUrl(url);
      });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Social Clone</h1>
      {auth.currentUser && <h1>Hi {auth?.currentUser?.displayName}</h1>}
      <Auth />
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="movie title..."
          onChange={(e) => setNewMovieTitle(e.target.value)} />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="release date"
          onChange={(e) => setNewReleaseDate(Number(e.target.value))} />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isNewMovieOscar}
          onChange={(e) => setIsNewMovieOscar(e.target.checked)}
        />
        <label>Oscar?</label>
        <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImageUpload(e.target.files[0])}/>
        <button onClick={onSubmitMovie}>Submit movie</button>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {movieList.map((movie) => (
          <div key={movie.id}>
            <img key={movie.movieUrl} src={movie.movieUrl} alt={movie.movieUrl}/>
            <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
            <h3>{movie.releaseDate}</h3>
            {movie.receivedAnOscar && <h3>Received an Oscar!!! </h3>}
            <button onClick={() => deleteMovie(movie.id)}>delete movie</button>
            <input placeholder="edit title" onChange={(e) => setUpdatedTitle(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => updateMovieTitle(movie.id)}>{" "}edit title</button>
            <hr />
          </div>
        )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hey guys, I've run into an issue I can't seem to get past.
My app is supposed to be able to get the info from the input fields and when you hit  submit movie it's supposed to display all the info. However, when I fill out the whole form, (enter title, year, oscar, and add an img file) and hit "submit movie", only the title, year and oscar comes up, but not the image. When I submit another movie, the title, year, oscar and the image that I submitted the first time comes up. I console.logged the url in the uploadFile function, and it shows up but only after everything else loads, which is what causes this weird bug.

But in the onSubmitMovie() function, the uploadFile() function should fire first, right? Or am I using async / await wrong?

I've also tried returning the url in the submitMovie function, but the result was the same.

I also tried using this function instead:

```
const uploadFile = async (id) => {
    if (imageUpload == null) return;
    const filesFolderRef = ref(storage, `projectFiles/${imageUpload.name + uniqid()}`)
    try {
      // const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(filesFolderRef, imageUpload);
      // const url = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
      // setNewMovieUrl(LOADING_IMAGE_URL);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Perhaps I should somehow use updateDoc? But I couldn't figure out the logistics of that yet.
I've only been coding for 4 months, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is one of timing. In your `uploadFile` function, you're using React state (`setNewMovieUrl`) to save your url, but your `onSubmitMovie` function calls `uploadFile` and then, when it successfully finishes, immediately calls `addDoc` and expects to have the `newMovieUrl`. The problem is that `setNewMovieUrl` is not synchronous - meaning that React does not immediately update that value. It queues the update with any other state updates and then tries to handle them together on the next state update. You and I may not notice this because it happens quickly, but not as quickly as your code goes from `uploadFile` to `addDoc`.

That's why you see the first movie on the second submission too. By the time you do your second submission, React has updated `newMovieUrl` from the first update, but has yet to do so from the second update. Hit it a third time and you'll see the second movie url.

There are ways to solve this using `useEffect` and splitting your `onSubmitMovie` function, but I think a more reasonable solution from a code architecture standpoint is to have `uploadFile` return the movie url and use that value in your `addDoc`:

```js
const uploadFile = async () => {
    const filesFolderRef = ref(storage, `projectFiles/${imageUpload.name + uniqid()}`);
    return uploadBytesResumable(filesFolderRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        console.log(url)
        setNewMovieUrl(url);
        return url;
      });
    });
  }
```

You still save the url in `newMovieUrl` in case you need it elsewhere, but you also immediately get it back so you can hand it to `addDoc`:

```js
const onSubmitMovie = async () => {
    // await uploadFile();
    try {
      const url = await uploadFile();
      await addDoc(moviesCollectionRef, {
        title: newMovieTitle,
        releaseDate: newReleaseDate,
        receivedAnOscar: isNewMovieOscar,
        userId: auth?.currentUser?.uid,
        movieUrl: url,
      });
      getMovieList();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```